# where can I find definition of Window functions of Spark/scala

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to find signature and explanation of `rank` function in `Spark` but couldn't. Where could I find it?

I tried this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package but I can't see `rank` there

Comment: `rank` is in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` [object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), you can find `Window` functions in [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec).

Comment: Thanks. I saw this construct `.selectExpr(...).groupBy(
col("CustomerId"), window(col("InvoiceDate"), "1 day"))`. It seems the `window` used here is different than what I had thought. Where is this `window` defined?

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in the comment above, `rank` is in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` [object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions). `Window` is a class in `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions` package. You can find it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec).

`window`, on the other hand, --with a lowercase w-- is a function in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` object. Just like in your example, *lowercase `window` is used with a time column **to bucketize rows or generate tumblings.*** You can find examples in the link I provided above. Just type "window" in the search bar for `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` object.

I hope it helps!